# Cannot recover Azure Database after Entity Framework Drop

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure

I have the answer to this and want to get it out there.

On a production database I mistakenly left the Entity Framework code first on. When I did a deploy of code the code caused a database drop when it queried the database and the database signature was out of sync with the code.

How do I get my data back?

When I went to restore the database in the azure portal nothing succeeded. Could not get it back. Raised support request with Microsoft and it took four days to recover data.

Restore always restored an empty database. What should I have done.

Point-in-time restores prior to the database drop did nothing but create more empty databases.

What should I do to get back my data?

Comment: Should probably write up on the Microsoft Docs site as a comment or find the right SO Documentation page to put this as it isn't really a question in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be late , but to avoid such problem in the future use `Application Setting` in your WebApp in Azure so you can store the Connection String for the deployment database for the WebApp and change to it automatically after you upload the project [more on this Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure)